# How do I convert STRING to VARBINARY in java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, varbinary

I have a `String` containing XML tags that I want to convert to `VARBINARY` and post it to stored procedure in SQL Server.

I don't know how to convert a `String` to `VARBINARY`. Please advise!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) you should be able to do something like this:

```
// This is your input string
String value = "SomeValue";

// Your query goes here
PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE TheTable SET XmlField = ? WHERE Id = ?");

// Convert the input string to bytes according to the UTF-8 character encoding
byte[] varBinary = value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Set the XmlField parameter in the prepared statement.
s.setBytes(1, varBinary)

// ID field
s.setInt(2, 42)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using [AppacheCommon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String str = "someSting";
byte[] b = Base64.decodeBase64(str);
```